# Convert Python code to verify webhook request into C#

Tags: python, c#, webhooks, digital-signature

I am following the documentation of a payment provider (Lemon Squeezy) where my application needs to verify that webhook requests are indeed coming from the provider. The documentation only has PHP, Node.js, and Python code examples. My application is written in C#.

This is the Python code provided in the documentation:

```
import hashlib
import hmac

signature = request.META['HTTP_X_SIGNATURE']
secret = '[SIGNING_SECRET]'

digest = hmac.new(secret.encode(), request.body, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

if not hmac.compare_digest(digest, signature):
    raise Exception('Invalid signature.')
```

The signing secret is being used to generate a hash of the payload and send the hash in the X-Signature header of the request. The signing secret is a password that I have set on the provider side and I'm storing locally and accessing through the configuration dependency injection. The signature is retrieved from the header, and the request body taken from the request.

With the help of Copilot, and some research online this is what I have at the moment.

```
var signature = Request.Headers["X-Signature"];
string secret = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Keys:LMWebhookSigningSecret");
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync(); 

using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret)))
{
    byte[] computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody));
    string digest = BitConverter.ToString(computedHash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

    if (!digest.Equals(signature))
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid signature.");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if my code is equivalent to the Python code but I think something is wrong because the digest is never equal to the signature.

This is the documentation btw: https://docs.lemonsqueezy.com/help/webhooks